# SQL - Where *** Like '%**%' Query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am new to SQL and have a question regarding a prewrote query. I would like to filter the results based on a 'like'.

The below is the query which works but bring up some information not required.

```
SELECT SU.[UserId]
  ,SU.[Surname]
  ,SU.[FirstName]
  ,ST.[TokenData]
  ,APG.[Description] [AccessPermissionGroup]
FROM [Sateon].[ac].[User] SU
  INNER JOIN [Sateon].[ac].[Token] ST ON ST.PermissionedEntityId = SU.UserId
  INNER JOIN [Sateon].[ac].[APG_PermissionedEntity] APG_Pe ON APG_Pe.PermissionedEntityId = SU.UserId
  INNER JOIN [Sateon].[ac].[AccessPermissionGroup] APG ON APG.AccessPermissionGroupId = APG_Pe.AccessPermissionGroupId
```

I would like a filter down the results based on the APG.[Description] [AccessPermissionGroup] field to only show (WHERE LIKE '%Lifts%') and ignore all the other data.

The below is the current results i am getting

[Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9UStH.png)

Can someone help please?

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean `WHERE APG.[Description] [AccessPermissionGroup] LIKE '%Lifts%`?

Comment: Please show us some sample data, and the expected results

Comment: Hi James, Yes this is what i mean,

Comment: [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/) - especially if you are using non-standard SQL

Answer (score 0):

you can use where clause in mysql like this

```sql
where APG.[Description] LIKE '%Lifts%'  AND 
 APG.[AccessPermissionGroup] LIKE '%Lifts%'
```

Comment: `AccessPermissionGroup` is an alias for `APG.Description`, so you don't want to filter also on that (I assume that column doesn't exist in APG)